# interpreting confusion matrix results

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, classification, naive-bayes

I have a dataset on unemployed individuals enrolled in a job training program where I am trying to predict whether 6 months post-enrolment they 1) gain employment, 2) stay unemployed, or 3) drop out of the workforce.
Based on my understanding of this [guide](https://medium.com/hugo-ferreiras-blog/confusion-matrix-and-other-metrics-in-machine-learning-894688cb1c0a), I should focus on the recall or sensitivity rate if my goal is to minimize false negatives.

Here is the code:

```
#Generating 493 numbers (75% of 657) without replacement
set.seed(300)
id_train <- sample(1:657, 493, replace = FALSE)
head(id_train, 10)

#Getting training set
dfmat_training <- dfm_subset(dfmt_teach, id_numeric %in% id_train)

#Getting test set (documents not in id_train)
dfmat_test <- dfm_subset(dfmt_teach, !id_numeric %in% id_train)

#Training the naive Bayes classifier using textmodel_nb()
tmod_nb <- textmodel_nb(dfmat_training, dfmat_training$outcome)
summary(tmod_nb)

#Naive Bayes can only take features into consideration that occur both in the training set and the test set, 
#but we can make the features identical using dfm_match()
dfmat_matched <- dfm_match(dfmat_test, features = featnames(dfmat_training))

#Inspecting how well the classifier worked
actual_class <- dfmat_matched$outcome
predicted_class <- predict(tmod_nb, newdata = dfmat_matched)
tab_class <- table(actual_class, predicted_class)
tab_class

#We can use the function confusionMatrix() from the caret package to assess the performance of the classification
confusionMatrix(tab_class, mode = "everything", positive = "pos")
```

I want to see if my interpretation here is correct on the confusion matrix results:
The model performed well at 0.8077, when it comes to correctly predicting if an individual dropped out of the workforce, but performed extremely poorly at correctly predicting outcomes for individuals who stayed unemployed at 0.18519, correct?

```
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.1387          

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: employment Class: unemployed Class: drop out of the workforce
Sensitivity             0.27273    0.18519                   0.8077
Specificity             0.88550    0.89051                   0.4000
Pos Pred Value          0.37500    0.25000                   0.7000
Neg Pred Value          0.82857    0.84722                   0.5455
Precision               0.37500    0.25000                   0.7000
Recall                  0.27273    0.18519                   0.8077
F1                      0.31579    0.21277                   0.7500
Prevalence              0.20122    0.16463                   0.6341
Detection Rate          0.05488    0.03049                   0.5122
Detection Prevalence    0.14634    0.12195                   0.7317
Balanced Accuracy       0.57911    0.53785                   0.6038
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it slightly differently, your model is

- able to catch 80.77% of the people who dropped out of workforce, and classified the rest otherwise
- able to catch only 18.52% of the people who are unemployed, and classified the rest otherwise

So, if an individual dropped out of the workforce, there is 80.77% change that he/she gets detected. But, the converse is not true. If the model predicts an individual as dropped out of the workforce, it doesn't mean it's true by 80.77%. That's what recall tells us.

Comment: Clear explanation, but then why are Sensitivity and Recall rates always the same for the three groups? Specifically, if the two rates are identical, does that allow us to conclude that that the model is correct in say 80.77% of the time for individuals who are out of the workforce or should be cautious with such statements?

Comment: Sensitivity and recall have the same values because they are the same.